# How to disable NextButton on TargetDirectory page

Tags: qt, installation, qt5, qt-installer, qtif

I am using Qt Installer Framework, I want to disable NextButton on TargetDirectory page. I tried editing controlscript.qs with few methods but it doesn't seem to work. Following is one of them

```
Controller.prototype.TargetDirectoryPageCallback = function()
{
    var widget = gui.currentPageWidget();
    if (widget != null) 
    {
        widget.BackButton.setEnabled(false) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to replace BackButton by NextButton. I think that it will be fine.

**Edit**
Check those links :

http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/noninteractive.html

http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/scripting-buttons.html

Inside your callback, try this line :

```
buttons.NextButton.setEnabled(false)
```

Comment: How to replace NextButton?

Comment: Very sorry to say it did not work. I am very much in need of this functionality but i don't know how to come up with a solution.

Comment: Can you please share a tested piece of code which may show how to make NextButton disabled?